# remove previously stored value of a checkbox in a session when user unchecks this checkbox

Tags: asp.net

I try to dynamically create checkboxes - all of them with assigned checkedChanged  event.

In the event handler i test if the checkbox is checked  and if so I sore the  value attribute in a session.
But here occurs a big problem for me.

For example a client decides to check one checkboxes and it's value attribute is added to the session, but then he suddenly decides that he doesn't want that checbox to be checked and he unchecks it - it's ok, but this value will stay stored in the session and I don't eant that.
So is there any way to delete this value when the user unchecks the checkbox

```
      protected void btnProba_Click(objectore  sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           lblProba.Text = ((String)Session["chk"]);

           // lblProba.Text = pr.ToString();
        }


        protected void checkChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;
        if (chk.Checked)
        {
            //lblProba.Text += chk.Text;
            //myche.Add(chk.Text);
            Session["chk"] += chk.InputAttributes["value"];
        }

}
        protected void ddlNumberTourists_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            chkddlchange = true;
            int numTourists = Convert.ToInt32(ddlNumberTourists.SelectedItem.Text);
            for (int i = 0; i < numTourists; i++)
            {

                                string connectionString = "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=excursion;Trusted_Connection=true";
                string query =
          "SELECT Extra_Charge_ID, Excursion_ID, Amout, Extra_Charge_Description FROM EXTRA_CHARGES WHERE Excursion_ID=" + mynewstring;
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

                try
                {

                    conn.Open();
                    SqlDataReader rd= cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    int s = 0;


                    while (rd.Read())
                    {   
                        CheckBox mycheckbox = new CheckBox();
                        mycheckbox.ID = "chkblextracharge" + i.ToString() + s.ToString();
                       mycheckbox.Text = rd["Extra_Charge_Description"].ToString();
                       mycheckbox.InputAttributes.Add("value", rd["Extra_Charge_ID"].ToString());

                       mycheckbox.AutoPostBack = true;
                       mycheckbox.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(checkChanged);
                       Page.FindControl("form1").Controls.Add(mycheckbox);

                                          }



                }//End of try

                catch (Exception ex)
                { }


            }//end of for


        }




    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you store checkboxes values as a concatenated string in `Session["chk"]`. It makes removing anything from there pretty hard. I guess it might be better to store a list of strings in `Session["chk"]`, so you would be able to easy add/remove entries from there...